# Inclusion- Exclusion Principle and Teacups.

Tags: probability

This is the question, it is just from my thinking that you may be able to use the inclusion-exclusion principle.

> A tea set has $n$ cups and $n$ saucers of $n$ different colours. If the cups are placed at random on the saucers, what is the probability that no cup is on a saucer of the same colour?

A previous question was the same but with $n=3$ and I answered it just by listing the possibilities and picking out the ones with no teacups and saucer colours in common. Any help or pointers to help me think of a way to do this?

Comment: For a good discussion of this problem, please see the Wikipedia article on [Derangements.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) And yes, Inclusion/Exclusion is useful for the general "formula."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is about computing what is called derangements. It is equivalent to counting the number of permutations of $n$ numbers that don't preserve the position of any.

As your title suggests, it can be approached by inclusion-excusion principle. We count the permutations that do preserve at least one position. Call $P(n_1,n_2,...,n_k)$ the number of permutations of $\{1,2,...,n\}$ that preserve the numbers $n_1,n_2,...,n_k$. It is clear that $p(n_1,n_2,...,n_k)=(n-k)!$.

Now, these permutations may be also preserving some other numbers as well. So, we must not count them.

We get $\sum_{i=1}^{n}p(i)-\sum_{i,j}p(i,j)+...+(-1)^{n-1}p(1,2,...,n)$.

The summands on each summation are equal, so we get

$$\binom{n}{1}(n-1)!-\binom{n}{2}(n-2)!+...+(-1)^{n-1}n\binom{n}{n}(n-n)!$$

The total number of permutation is $n!$. From there you can get the probability.

Comment: Should the exponent on the $-1$ not be $n+1$? As if $n$ even the value should be $-1$.

Comment: An interesting formula for the number of derangements on $n$ elements is $!n = \left[\dfrac{n!}{e}\right],$ where $[x]$ is not the floor function, but the nearest integer (rounding) function.